# iOS project can't run when AIR SDK upgraded to 3.6

Tags: ios5, air

That is very simple flash iOS project with `FB 4.7`, `AIR SDK 3.6`, and running on `iPad2(5.1.1)`.

When I debug with the default `AIR SDK 3.4` of `FB 4.7`, the project is running ok. But, when I upgrade the `AIR SDK` to `3.6` according the help of [Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html). The `FB 4.7` debuger can't connect to running process, and the "hello world" doesn't show as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what's wrong with the problem.

The key is the step 4. in Adobe AIR SDK Upgrade [Help](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html).

Copy the contents from the aot folder (AIRSDK_back_up\lib\aot) of the AIR SDK backup to the aot folder of the newly created AIR SDK (AIRSDK\lib\aot).

Don't copy all contents from the aot folder, just copy **strip** from lib\aot\bin to the aot bin folder of the newly created AIR SDK 3.6 (AIRSDK\lib\aot\bin).

Then, I restart the FB 4.7, the "hello world!" show as well.